# How to define a class wide rescue method for Timeout::error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timeout, savon

I have a class that uses savon as a gem to speak with a SOAP API. And from times to times the server is unreachable so the methods that implement the soap methods throw a `Timeout::Error`. Its not a problem to implement a rescue like this:

```
begin 
  ...
rescue Timeour::Error 
  ...
end
```

But I have ~50 methods defined that might be affected and I dont want to repeat the same code 50 times. Thats abolutely not dry. Is there a way to deal with this? I already thought about sth like this:

```
def safe_call method, params
  begin
    self.send method, params
  rescue Timeour::Error
    # do sth heroic to rescue the method
  end
end
```

But thats pretty unawesome because I have to change each call in all scripts that use the class. Is there a way to do a class wide rescue?

Comment: Do you want to recover from that error, or just ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use rescue_from. You can read about it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

In short, you can put this in your application controller:

```
rescue_from 'Timeout::Error' do |exception|
  # Rescue logic here.
end
```